# I have input a unique "key" prop but still got error asking me to input it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, key

so this is my render, it render basically a ui where a username and their email. it also have the option to add new user but when I run the code in my local host, i get this error in my console: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div key={user._id} className="box">
                <h3>{user.name}</h3>
                <h4>{user.email}</h4>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.beginEdit(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Update
                </button>
                
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.deleteUser(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderAddUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my AddRenderUser

```
  // render new User 
  renderAddUser() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment >
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="User name"
          value={this.state.newUserName}
          onChange={this.updateFormField}
          name="newUserName"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="User email"
          value={this.state.newUserEmail}
          onChange={this.updateFormField}
          name="newUserEmail"
        />
        <button onClick={this.addUser}>Add</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Although I did put the keys props in my div, so not sure how to correct this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I add the unique key attribute when mapping through an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73683219/where-should-i-add-the-unique-key-attribute-when-mapping-through-an-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the key prop to the React.Fragment tag like this:

```
<React.Fragment key={user._id}>
```

Or please try to use index value instead of user.id as follows:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.users.map((user, i) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
              <div className="box">
                <h3>{user.name}</h3>
                <h4>{user.email}</h4>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.beginEdit(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Update
                </button>
                
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.deleteUser(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderAddUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: i still get the same error when i click "add"

Comment: Can you share your code for renderAddUser?

Comment: hi i added my renderAddUser

Comment: Please try to use index value instead of user._id. I updated my answer.

Comment: does using index value affect my state variable id

Comment: What your state variable id? Did you check my solution on your end?

Comment: i use math.random to generate

Comment: no problem. Please try to use my above code.

Comment: That index value i is the second parameter of map function.

Comment: Using an index as a key is bad practice and could confuse React into making unnecessary renders. 
Please refer to: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more info if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Your key should be in your top-most element

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={user._id}>
              <div  className="box">
                <h3>{user.name}</h3>
                <h4>{user.email}</h4>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.beginEdit(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Update
                </button>
                
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.deleteUser(user);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderAddUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i still get the same error when i click "add"

Comment: what does `add` do?

Comment: it add a new user

Comment: where does the `user._id` come from ?

Comment: it comes from my state variables

Comment: state = {
    users: [
      {
        _id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        name: "Jon Snow",
        email: "jonsnow@winterfell.com"
      },

Comment: it is advised to use a unique value for your key. Are the user emails unique ?

Comment: is just sample emails so nope

Comment: can you add the exact error message in your question please ?